# sed to update xml file

Tags: sed

I want to update

```
<MySettingsSettings enabled="false" logFilePath="E:\server.log" />
```

to

```
<MySettingsSettings enabled="true" logFilePath="D:\server.log" />
```

How can I do this through sed? or is there any other way to update in a windows server?

Comment: Ah, fun! Editing xml/html with regular expressions.  Madness may be in your future. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion, is that you use a real programming language that can actually parse and update XML/HTML documents properly.  Using sed to update XML/HTML will probably fail in the long run.

Comment: +1 : Didn't notice this was a XML file.

Comment: I am just assuming it is xml/html.  But it sure looks like it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple substitution from your example can be done like this:

```
sed -e 's/enabled="true"/enabled="false"/g' -e 's/logFilePath="D:/logFilePath="C:/g' myfile.xml
```

However, I would agree with Zoredache's warning that unless you are only doing a very simple string replacement inside XML, you'd be better off with a language that has libraries available specifically built for parsing XML.

A great resource for a multitude of handy sed commands is the "sed one-liner" file:

http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt